# Automating Excel in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm working on a project that requires a lot of complicated calculations that I want to do in Excel, but want to keep a database in Access.

As a basic example, if I have a table in Access such as

```
+---------+---------+-----+
| Number1 | Number2 | Sum |
+---------+---------+-----+
|    1    |    1    |     |
|    1    |    2    |     |
|    2    |    2    |     |
+---------+---------+-----+
```

where I would want to calculate the Sum of each row of Number1 and Number2 in Excel then put the result back into my Access table, how would I go about that? I'm fairly new to Access and have been pretty unsuccessful in finding an example of this scenario.

Comment: If you are only trying to SUM (or do other operators like multiply or divide existing data), why not use the built-in SQL capabilities inside of MS Access to create a calculated field which does the math for you and populates a new field?

Comment: I need to do some more complicated calculations in Excel that I won't really be able to do in Access easily. My main problem right now is just automating Excel in Access, not doing the calculations themselves, so I just used a simple example of SUM.

Comment: Can you open the Access table as a recordset in Excel and do your calculations on those recordset values?  Or do you need the Access data imported into a worksheet?

Comment: I tried using this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd789430(v=office.12).aspx


Using that I've been able to use recordset to open the Access table in Excel and do the calculations, but I'm stuck on how to take the final values and put them back into my Access table.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a named range in Excel that includes the calculated results and a Key field, you can link from Access to that Excel range.

With the linked table the original data in Access can be changed with an update query.

To link an Excel range I used that code:

```
Sub MountExcel(MyPathToExcelFile, MyTblName, ExcelRange)
Dim ExternalExcel As TableDef

    Set ExternalExcel = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(MyTblName)
    With ExternalExcel
        .Connect = "Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=" & MyPathToExcelFile
        .SourceTableName = ExcelRange
    End With
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append ExternalExcel
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
End Sub
```

Some times F5 must be pressed before the new linked table is visible in the Access object list.